# Animate cells in a collection view

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, flowlayout

I have a horizontal collection view, which has one row. I want that the first time the view controller loads my first cell which animates in from the left and subsequent cells animate in from the right.

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this solution to your question.
This is not one as per your requirement but you can refer the code and create animation as per your requirement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398148/8334818